# WP not sending any emails

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I'm having problems with sending emails to a theme that I bought in themeforest. The emails from new users and from the contact form doesn't arrive at my email, despite the message that the email was sent.

It all started when I bought the theme and tried to send an email, the following message appeared:

```
"/usr/sbin/sendmail: not found"
```

Then I entered my EC2 Ubuntu instance through the terminal and downloaded and installed with apt-get sendmail..

I thought it had worked because of the message that began to appear when I tried to send a message .. "message successfully sent".... but, it didn't.

The support said to me there i should use the WP mail function, not the PHP mail function.. i change it in the dashboard.. and.. nothing.

Searching a lot i discover that no emails are being send at all, not just in the form.

I already try to search for errors in my error.log in apache2 and there isn't..

I know that i have the support to help me, but they are not answer me anymore.. so.. any helps is very welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: WP Mail still uses php mail(). Make sure PEAR mail is properly installed and configured and that should fix this.

Comment: I'm very bad with wordpress, how could i do that?

Comment: That's a server configuration issue, not a WP issue. Some pointers on [checking if PEAR is installed](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php). If confused, try looking on server fault for help on checking if PEAR mail is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not real handy with WordPress internals, you should find an appropriate email plugin.

I really like using the Mandrill mailer service. It's free if you send 12K messages a month or less. Install this plugin, and follow the Mandrill directions. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpmandrill/

You can also use an SMTP plugin if you have access to an SMTP mail relay.  There are a couple of them. Search the [plugin directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/) for the right plugin, and ask your hosting provider about SMTP.

Finally, you can ask your hosting provider to help you get email configured correctly. Your error message shows that it is not.  Read this, or even better, ask your service provider to read it and fix your setup.  http://php.net/manual/en/mail.requirements.php

Comment: +1, It's arguably best to use an SMTP mail relay or something like Mandrill regardless of how well you know the internals of WordPress.